# FROM keyword not found where expected - basic query

Tags: oracle, plsql

I don't understand why this is not working (my production query is much more complicated):

```
select *, rownum from (
select 1 from dual);
```

I am getting ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected error.

What is wrong with this query?

Comment: If you select `*` (not qualified by a table name or alias), then it must be the **only** thing in the `select` list. If you must also select `rownum`, then you **must** qualify the `*`. To be able to do that with a subquery, as you have, you must give an alias to the subquery and use that to qualify the `*`. As in the Answer from Justin Cave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd need an alias on your inline view and on the `*` in your `select` list

```
select a.*, rownum 
  from (select 1 from dual) a;
```